# How can I fix these TypeErrors in my Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am getting a few errors:

- line 12: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`
- line 14: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guilds' of undefined`

I might have a few other errors that I haven't seen yet.

How can I fix these errors?

Here is the code for my Discord bot:

```
console.log("hi");
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'token';

client.on('ready', async client => {
    console.log('This bot is online');

    client.user.setActivity("Youtube", {type: "Watching"})
    
    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(guild.name)
        guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
            console.log(` - ${channel.name}  ${channel.type}  ${channel.id}`)
        })
        //general text id: 721950719657115750
    })

    const jpg = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/709199176562638849/722646217930178620/OIPK7JS66QT.jpg"
    const img = await randomPuppy(jpg);
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setImage(img)
            .setTitle(`From /r/${random}`)
            .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`);

        message.channel.send(embed);
})

client.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content === "hello"){
        msg.reply('hello')
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: It looks like client is undefined..that's why it is showing cannot read user of undefined as you are accessing user property on undefined client object...I suggest you go through the already existing answers in the SO. Thanks !

Comment: Please regenerate your Discord bot token because this one was made public. Never share your token and use environment variables for secrets.